# Error when enabling PHP extensions

Tags: php, apache, windows-xp

I have PHP 5.4.11 VC9 and Apache 2.4.3 (apacheLounge) running on Win XP SP3.

I wanted to use `mb_convert_encoding`, but i got:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mb_convert_encoding()

I have found that I need to enable the extension `php_mbstring.dll`. But when I remove the `;` at the beginning and restart Apache, in my php error log file I get:

> [26-Jan-2013 19:40:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on
>   line 0
>
> [26-Jan-2013 19:40:15 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on
>   line 0

I have tried to disable it and enable other extensions, but I get the same error (the two lines each time). And if I disable all extensions, there is no error.

Ah, and when I enable `php_mbstring.dll`, it doesn't work because I can't call `mb_convert_encoding()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved it adding the PHP folder to the PATH and restarting the computer.

Comment: I can confirm that PHP loads certain extensions (`gd` in my case) from the system's `PATH` environment variable even when it points to the correct `php.ini` file. This makes it terribly complicated to run two PHP versions side by side.